# MacOS switch back and forth between windows of the same app

Tags: macos, mac, macos-ventura

In MacOS Ventura, how can I switch back and forth between windows of the same app? I want the same behavior that alt-tab provide instead of the "cycle" or "next window" behavior, but for windows of the same app instead of different apps. I know this is possible with "cmd+tick" and "cmd+shift+tick", but I don't want to remember which one to press depending on the current window. That's just cognitive load I want to remove from my workflow.

Comment: You can't force behaviour to match cmd/tab, it will always cycle, not alternate. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275

Comment: :( This is something that Windows and Linux already have. I can't believe MacOS, a premium OS, is lagging behind on these productivity user experience tools that everyone else has.

Comment: Have you had a look on AskDifferent? I found this that has a wide variety of solutions that might be helpful. While you can certainly ask Mac questions here you *might* have a little better success over there. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/best-app-to-switch-between-all-open-windows